# How to add a page number to the included PDF pages?

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm creating a documentation with some included pdf files (mostly diagrams or tables) in the following way.

```
 \includepdf[pages=1-10, angle=90]{requirements/Requirements.pdf}
```

The command "includepdf" is supported by the package "pdfpages".
My problem now is all of the included pdf pages don't have any page numbers, except for page numbers which where directly in the PDF's itself.

Is it possible to print them? Or is there any other way to include a PDF, show it on the full page and print a page number?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
 \includepdf[pages=1-10, angle=90, pagecommand={}]{requirements/Requirements.pdf}
```

Add `pagecommand={}` as one of your options.

Answer (score 53):

If you need page numbers at the bottom,

```
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},
  pages=1-10, angle=90]{requirements/Requirements.pdf}
```

Change "plain" to "headings" if you are in the report or book class and want for the included pages the same style as the others.

Comment: What about beamer?

Comment: @wok I'm afraid that with `beamer` things are very different and `\thispagestyle` has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Although a different question but responding to [Wok](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1567/wok) for beamer:

```tex
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/221216)