# Base document page numbers with pdfpages

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm writing a report, in LaTeX. And I need to include, as appendices, other latex documents I have written. I am currently doing this using `pdfpages` and it works. However, the inserted PDF has no page numbers and it overlays my base documents page numbering, resulting in no page numbers on the PDF pages. My questions:

1. How to solve the above problem.
2. Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: As far as I know, pdfpages simply embeds the pages from the other PDFs without recompiling them. I don't think PDF pages has the capacity to edit the inserted PDF at all. If the appendices are your own, why not insert the source with `\include` or `\input`? That way it'll recompile and produce consistent page numbers.

Comment: I initially did try with both, using \input it would not compile (not sure why) with \include it compiled but the included document wasnt there. So pdf pages provided the simplest solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`pdfpages` provides the `pagecommand` option for `\includepdf`, which can be used to apply a page style for each page, to print headings and more. For example, add plain page style or your own page style to get page numbers on all included pages:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{filename}
```

Comment: This was better for me: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21249/1567

Answer (score 14):

You can also include the next command, for all pdfs that will be put into the document,

```
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

This command goes after `\usepackage{pdfpages}`.

Answer (score 4):

This keeps the pagestyle:

> `\includepdf[pages=myPageNumber, pagecommand={}]{myPresentation.pdf}`

However, it does not increment the page number accordingly.

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21249/1567