# Base document page numbers with pdfpages and nup

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

It's possible to have `pdfpages` number the pages of the document it including using the following command:

```
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

(cf. [Base document page numbers with pdfpages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/base-document-page-numbers-with-pdfpages) )

Unfortunately, this doesn't play nicely with `nup` (which puts multiple source pages on one target page); the numbering is applied to the output pages rather than the input pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[nup=2x3,pages={1-6},frame=true]{<use any PDF file>}
\end{document}
```

Cf. the '1' at the bottom of this, where I would want 1-6 on the pages:

[image]

Is there any way around this?

Comment: This is the expected output, so you'll have to change the way `\thepage` is printed in order to achieve the desired output. It will also have to be done somewhat manually, since the page numbers of the input document could be *anything*. That's just my opinion.

Comment: @Werner: numbering 1-6 (regardless of the source numbering) would be fine.

Comment: Are you interested in referencing these page numbers 1-6? Not the included "nup"-ed pages, but the target page numbers?

Comment: @Werner: I want to label the small 'nup'-ed pages 1-6. The context is that in the image in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/illustrating-a-multi-page-mwe , I realised one couldn't tell whether the "small" pages 1,2,3,4 went across or down -- having pdfpages number them would fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two stages. The first stage just adds the page number, e.g.:

```
%%% test-stage1.tex %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[fitpaper,pages={1-6}]{test-org.pdf}
\end{document}
%%% test-stage1.tex %%%
```

The next stage uses `nup`:

```
\documentclass{article}% set the correct paper size, default is letterpaper
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[nup=2x3,pages={1-6},frame=true]{test-state1.pdf}
\end{document}
```