# Header when the chapter contains pdf pages

Tags: header-footer

The style of my PhD thesis is compilation of published or accepted prepared manuscript with a general introduction (review of relevant literature), general discussion, summary and conclusion. So, I have to add multiple pdf files as published papers within the Lyx/tex environment as different chapters. 
I have added them but the problem that these chapters don't show header.
Is there any way to show the header of those chapters?
Any help will be appreciated with thanks and gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{addedPdfHere}
```

You can also define what command should be executed inside `pagecommand`. From package documentation:

> pagecommand Declares LaTeX commands, which are executed on each sheet
>   of paper. (Default: `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`)

Credits to [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/base-document-page-numbers-with-pdfpages) answers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Probably I have not been able to clarify the question. I have no problem to add multiple pdf pages using following command: \includepdf[page=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Cattle.pdf} My question is to show the header in the added chapters

Comment: I found the solution of this problem from other answer. the command to include header of a embedded pdf chapter will be like this one:\includepdf[page=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\section*{Brucellosis in PUO patient}\hfill}]{Human3.pdf}