# Use includepdf in beamer class and keep pagestyle but counting up the pages

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, pdfpages

I'm creating a beamer document in that several PDF documents get included by a python script.
To keep the style of the slides and including the PDFs I'm using the \includepdf like that:

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\includepdf[pages={1-},width = 0.9\\textwidth,pagecommand={}]{*Path}
```

The *Path gets replaced with the PDF name by the python script.
The problem is, that the page numbers are not getting updated with the added PDFs.

On the other hand I found at: [Base document page numbers with pdfpages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/base-document-page-numbers-with-pdfpages)

A way to add the page numbers with:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{filename}
```

But in that case my header and footer get lose.

Does someone as an idea how to combine both?

Greetings

Stefan

**EDIT**

A (hopefully) MWE that shows my problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%%---------FootLine------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep\fill}c c c c}
    \hline
     & & & \\
    & \insertshorttitle & \today &   {\insertframenumber}
\end{tabular*} 
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \hspace{2em}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=8.25ex,dp=3.5ex]{}%
    \raggedright  
    \vbox to 7.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\sffamily\Large\color{orange}\insertsection}\vfil}\\
    \vbox to0.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\sffamily\Large\color{orange}\insertsubsection}\vfil}    
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip-3pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.6ex,dp=1ex]{black_white}%
    \raggedright
    \hspace*{2em}
    {\normalsize\insertframetitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
    \section*{First Section}
    \begin{frame}
        Hello1
    \end{frame}
    \newpage
    \begin{frame}
        Hello2
    \end{frame}
    \section*{PDF Test}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
    \includepdf[pages={-},width=0.9\textwidth,pagecommand={}]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \incloudegraphics[page=1,height=\textheight] will put a single page into the text area.  (This is actually what pdfpages uses.)

Comment: But with \includegraphics I just can include one page of the PDF document, I want to include l want to include all pages (about 60 pages).

Comment: One page per \includgraphics.  If you had provided an MWE I could show you how to write a loop.  BTW, a 60 page beamer presentation?

Comment: What does MWE mean?
Yes the presentation is a measurement report that should be in that format. The final presentation will be about 150 pages.

Comment: MWE stands for "minimal working example" and means a short but compilable document around your command.  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Have you tried pagecommand=\thispagestyle{heading} or \thispagestyle{fancy} (for fancyhrd) yet?

Comment: Yes I did but not with the expected result.
Maybe the problem is the way I put the page number into the footer.
Therefor I use '\insertframenumber', is there an better alternative?

I have an little example that shows my problem, how can I upload here with the included PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by following your loop tip.
I included the forloop package, read out the maximum page number of the PDF document in python and create the for loop just when needed.

Just for your information, that is the test code of my solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{forloop}

%%---------FootLine------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep\fill}c c c c}
    \hline
     & & & \\
    & \insertshorttitle & \today &   {\insertframenumber}
\end{tabular*} 
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \hspace{2em}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=8.25ex,dp=3.5ex]{}%
    \raggedright  
    \vbox to 7.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\sffamily\Large\color{orange}\insertsection}\vfil}\\
    \vbox to0.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\sffamily\Large\color{orange}\insertsubsection}\vfil}    
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip-3pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.6ex,dp=1ex]{black_white}%
    \raggedright
    \hspace*{2em}
    {\normalsize\insertframetitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
    \section*{First Section}
    \begin{frame}
        Hello1
    \end{frame}
    \newpage
    \begin{frame}
        Hello2
    \end{frame}
    \section*{PDF Test}
    \newcounter{ct}
    \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 4}%
    {%
        \begin{frame}
            \includegraphics[page=\value{ct}, width=0.9\textwidth]{test.pdf}
        \end{frame}
    }
\end{document}
```

@JohnKormylo Thanks for your advice!