# Can I include an article (revtex4) inside a book-class latex document?

Tags: books, revtex

I would like to include in an Appendix of my thesis some articles written, and I would like to do so in the original style which is revtex-prl. The thesis is written as a book.

Can I actually do this?

Answer (score 4):

IF you have your articles as PDFs, you could use the `pdfpages` package

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
Some text before \dots

\includepdf[pages={1-4,6}]{pdffilename}

Some more text.
\end{document}
```

The inclusion works independently form the pdf it just puts the pages in. One can even specify a header (e.g. pagemark) for the included pages.

Comment: Is there any way to continue with the previous numbering in the inserted PDFs using the includepdf function?

Comment: @Urko: I’m not sure what you mean :-) which numbering should be continued? The page numbering? Then the answer is kind of yes: it is possible to stamp page numbers on included PDFs with `pagecommand`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21248/4918 for instance. If this is not what you are looking for you are welcome to ask a follow up question (include an explanation what you want an a MWE …)