# Title page not showing up in subfile{} when included in main.tex

Tags: document-classes, article, report, subfiles

I am compiling a different documents of article class type and I am using a main tex file of report class to compile it into one pdf file. I used subfile{} to do so but the \maketitle{} page in documents are not showing up. How can I make it so without complicating anything?
My main tex file say `Lab_Report.tex` looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %article also works
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{}
\begin{document}



\maketitle 
\subfile{report1}
\subfile{report2}



\end{document}
```

my `report.tex` looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%assume all necessary packages included


\title{Report 1 - Make something}
\date{1st April 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\subsection*{Aim:}
To do something
\subsection*{Apparatus:}
Whatever you have now
\end{document}
```

The end result is that all included files are present but without the \maketitle page. I am quite new to Latex so my code might seem silly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue ....

Comment: Are you using the `subfiles` package? If so, don't the subfiles need to be of the subfiles class rather than the article class? In any case, don't make us guess. Provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @Mensch There are many files involved in this. The code is error free just that it doesn't show the title page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vaishnav How are we supposed to know when you provide us with such little information? We are not clairvoyant. You didn't even answer my first question. Please click the link in my previous comment and learn how to make a MWE.

Comment: @frabjous I'm really sorry. However, I made my work by merging pdfs. It was quite urgent so I couldn't provide the MWE. However, I will soon update the details with the MWE for the sake of learning so that I can apply it in future. To answer your Question, The 'subfiles' I used were of the class article and they did work but only left out the title page. The main tex was of class report. It would take too much time to change the```doc class``` and change the code for 6 other documents in short time so I had to resort to merging PDFs using ```pdfpages``` package and using ```\includepdf[]{}```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subfiles package is not meant to be used the way you were trying to
use it. The included files are meant to be parts of the main document,
not separate documents with a different document class. In fact, I'm
surprised you didn't just get errors when you tried to use it with
the subfiles having the "article" document class. All subfiles are
supposed to use the "subfiles" document class.

See its [documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf), which reads:

> The subfiles have to start with the line:
>
> `\documentclass[main file name]{subfiles}`
>
> which loads the class subfiles. Its only ‘option’, which is actually
> mandatory, gives the name of the main file. This name follows TEX
> conventions: .tex is the default extension, the path has to be
> provided if the main file is in a different directory, and directories
> in the path have to be separated by / (not ). Thus, we have the
> following structure.
>
> If LATEX is run on the subfile, the line `\documentclass[..]{subfiles}`
> is replaced by the preamble of the main file (including its
> `\documentclass` command). The rest of the subfile is processed
> normally.

As you can see, the subfiles are not supposed to have their own preambles. The package replaces their preambles with the preamble of the main document. Their own preambles are ignored. So the `\title` and `\date` commands in your example preambles are just being ignored when the main file is compiled.

Moreover, a single document doesn't usually have multiple `\maketitle` commands in it. If you need to have multiple `\maketitle` commands, you would need to load the `titling` package.

As I see it, you have three options.

### Option A

This is closest to what you were trying. Load the `titling` package in the main file, to allow for multiple `\maketitle` commands.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Main title}
\author{Author}
\date{Main date}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\subfile{report1}
\subfile{report2}

\end{document
```

Move the `\title` and `\date` commands in the subfiles to *after* `\begin{document}` so they are actually registered (remember the premable is ignored). You can remove any `\usepackage` commands; they are ignored too. Just make sure the packages you needed are loaded in the main file.

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\title{Report 1 - Make something}
\date{1st April 2022}
\maketitle
\subsection*{Aim:}
To do something
\subsection*{Apparatus:}
Whatever you have now
\end{document}
```

Of course, the article class is not used at all here, so the titles will be in the style of `report` (that is, they will be title pages rather than just a heading) by default. The titling package however does let you change the style of the titles. See its [documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf).

### Option B

Treat the subfiles as "chapters" of the report, since the report class supports chapters, and indeed, expects them. (Your `\subsection`s are not numbered, but if they were, you would notice the numbering starts with 0.0 for the chapter/section as no chapter or section commands were given.) This option actually makes more sense to me, since it uses the report class more the way it was intended.

The subfiles would then be simpler:

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Report 1 - Make something} % remove the * if you want it numbered
\subsection*{Aim:}
To do something
\subsection*{Apparatus:}
Whatever you have now
\end{document}
```

Then instead of new `\maketitle` commands, you could just use the chapter heading. If you need to style the chapter headings, or put them on their own pages, something like the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package would allow for that (including adding a date if you needed that).

### Option C

You can do what you did. Prepare many separate `article` class documents, and combine with a main file that uses the `pdfpages` package, or use a similar tool. This option makes more sense to me if your separate documents really are separate "articles" and not chapters of a single work, and you just need them in a single PDF for some reason

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Will I be able to run the subfiles individually or I'll have to load it in the main report tex and then debug?? Also Will I be able to add chapters and Number the pages continuously using ```pdfpages```?

Comment: You can run the files individually with the subfiles package, yes. That's the main point of the package as opposed to using `\include` or `\input` instead. You can add page numbers with pdfpages, yes: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/how-to-add-a-page-number-to-the-included-pdf-pages). If you go that route and need correct chapter numbers, you may need to set them manually with `setcounter{chapter}{4}` right before `\chapter{..}` for Chapter 5, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much