# How to introduce another tex file with its own preambles into a main tex file

Tags: include, multiple-files, combine

My coauthor and I have a tex file for the paper (main.tex), and another tex file for tables and figures (tables_and_figures.tex). Previously, we would compile main.tex, and then compile tables_and_figures.tex to start at the next page number. *I'm curious if it is possible to refer to tables_and_figures.tex in main.tex so that we just have to compile main.tex, and it will start tables_and_figures.tex following the content.* Importantly, tables_and_figures.tex has its own preambles, which seems to be incompatible with \include or \input (if my understanding of these commands based on the few postings is correct).

Comment: Do you need to `\ref` or anything similar to create references/links from `main.tex` to specific pages/elements of `tables_and_figures.tex`? If not, you could just add the compiled PDF for `tables_and_figures.tex` at the end of `main.tex` with the [pdfpages package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages?lang=en). If you need linked references, it's more difficult.

Comment: If I understand, this approach will require me to manually check how many pages are in main.tex, and then manually set the page number from which tables_and_figures.tex needs to start? If possible, we want to automate this part.

Comment: If you mean you want the the tables to appear in both documents (rather than reference the first document from the second) by far the simplest way is to put the body of the table document (with no preamble) into (say) `shared.tex` then `\input` that into each document.

Comment: You could remove the page numbers from tables_and_figures.tex and just continue the page numbers from main.tex using `pagecommand={}`. I.e., `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{tables_and_figures}`. (pdfpages usually supresses the page numbers of the pages it adds, but this makes it not do so; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/how-to-add-a-page-number-to-the-included-pdf-pages)).