# Appendix pagenumbering / includepdf

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, appendices, pdfpages

I have a question regarding the pagenumbering in the toc and also on the pages of my appendices.

TOC:
I would like all numbering as for I (chapter) the others are appendix sections and have different numbering style. And I would like them to be aligned right.

[image]

PAGES:
The appendices are \includepdf files and unfortunately the pages don't get numbered. So from  chapter I onwards, there is no pagenumbering on the actual pages.

```
%% appendix.tex
\part*{Appendices}

\includepdf[pages=1,picturecommand*={\put(133,660){\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{{Test}\label{app:Test}}}}}, scale=0.8, offset=80 -80]{appendices/Test.pdf}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix my issues?
Thanks :-)

Comment: If the linked page from the comment above does not help, please show a minimal working example from `\documentclass` over `\begin{document}` down to `\end{document}`, that can be used to reproduce your problem and find a solution.

Comment: First link worked for alignment of pagenumbering.

Comment: But it remains the issue with no pagenumbering on the actual pages due to \includepdf.

Comment: Never ask more than one question in one question. If you have several questions ask several questions and always add a minimal working example suitable for the one question.

Comment: For the additional question see: [How to add a page number to the included PDF pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21248/how-to-add-a-page-number-to-the-included-pdf-pages)

Comment: @cabohah thanks so much for the help. I will remember it for the next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Option `pagecommand` of `\includepdf` sets `\thispagestyle{empty}` by default. If you don't like this, disable it with `pagecommand={}`.
2. Use option `addtotoc` to generate TOC entries.

```
\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={1, section, 1, First PDF, sec:first},
  pagecommand={}
]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
```

To reference this document use `\ref{sec:first}.`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but is missing the section title of the appendix above the included pdf.

Comment: I got the title now, thanks for the quick help!